# Spring boot - setting up a global error handler to shield REST endpoints

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application with restful endpoints. I want to have a global error handler that basically traps any exceptions so that I can then manage the response (i.e. dont want to expose a big java stacktrace in the response)

Whats the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a controller advice class with an exception handler that will cache all exceptions of your desired type.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GlobalExceptionHandler.class);

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public void handleAll(Exception e) {
        log.error("Unhandled exception occurred", e);
    }

}
```

If you like, you can return a body from the method just like from a regular controller method or simply return some HTTP status code. The above code returns 500 using the `@ResponseStatus` annotation.

You can catch only specific exception types. The `@ExceptionHandler` annotation accepts an array of exceptions as the value attribute.